# How to run silverlight web-service on iis server?

Tags: web-services, silverlight, iis, service

i'm want to upload my project to my server, i'm using IIS on my server.
my project is a silverlight project that use a web-service. 
do i need to do something on my iis to run the web-service?
install somthing? 
i tried just to put the web-service on the iis but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's important to put the service on the wwwroot folder in iis, other way it will be restricted.
also it's important to put a crossdomain policy xml in the wwwroot and client crossdomain